# Dynamically Changing the Base Currency

Tags: swiftui, ios14

I have a currency API that returns a JSON object containing a strange arrangement: the base currency is used as a label. Typical currency APIs have labels like "base", "date", "success", and "rates", but this API doesn't have any of those.

```
{
    "usd": {
        "aed": 4.420217,
        "afn": 93.3213,
        "all": 123.104693,
        "amd": 628.026474,
        "ang": 2.159569,
        "aoa": 791.552347,
        "ars": 111.887966,
        "aud": 1.558363,
        "awg": 2.164862,
        "azn": 2.045728,
        "bam": 1.9541,
        "bbd": 2.429065,
        "bch": 0.001278
    }
}
```

The "usd" (US dollars) at the top is called the base or home currency. At the moment the storage structure and state parameter are hardcoded to "usd" which prevents using exchange rates with other base currencies.  The exchange rate API works great for a base currency of US dollars.

I need help modifying things so that I can download the exchange rates with different base currencies. For example, can I use a string variable in the storage model and state parameter?  Any enlightenment will be greatly appreciated.

```
struct RateResult: Codable {
        let usd: [String: Double]
    }    

   @State private var  results = RateResult(usd: [:])


struct ContentView: View {

   var body: some View {

   }

   func UpdateRates() {

      let baseUrl = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fawazahmed0/currency-api@1/latest/currencies/"
        let baseCur = baseCurrency.baseCur.baseS   // usd
        let requestType = ".json"
        
        guard let url = URL(string: baseUrl + baseCur + requestType) else {
            print("Invalid URL")
            return
        }
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            if let data = data {
                if let decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(RateResult.self, from: data) {
                    
                    // we have good data – go back to the main thread
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        
                        // update our UI
                        self.results = decodedResponse
                        
                    // save off currency exchange rates
                    
                    }
                    // everything is good, so we can exit
                    return
                }
            }
            // if we're still here it means there was a problem
            print("Currency Fetch Failed: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: It’s difficult to understand what this question is about, is it really a SwiftUI issue or is it about how to handle your data structures or even how to download?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import SwiftUI
//You can't use the standard Codable for this. You have to make your own.
class BaseCurrency: Codable {
    let id = UUID()
    var baseCurrencies: [String : [String: Double]] = [:]
    required public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        do{
            print(#function)
            let baseContainer = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
            let base = try baseContainer.decode([String : [String: Double]].self)
            for key in base.keys{
                baseCurrencies[key] = base[key]
            }
        }catch{
            print(error)
            throw error
        }
    }
    //@State should never be used outside a struct that is a View
}
struct CurrencyView: View {
    @StateObject var vm: CurrencyViewModel = CurrencyViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            List{
                if vm.results != nil{
                    ForEach(vm.results!.baseCurrencies.sorted{$0.key < $1.key}, id: \.key) { key, baseCurrency in
                        DisclosureGroup(key){
                            ForEach(baseCurrency.sorted{$0.key < $1.key}, id: \.key) { key, rate in
                                HStack{
                                    Text(key)
                                    Text(rate.description)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    Text("waiting...")
                }
            }
            //To select another rate to go fetch
            RatesPickerView().environmentObject(vm)
        }.onAppear(){
            vm.UpdateRates()
        }
    }
}
struct RatesPickerView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var vm: CurrencyViewModel
    var body: some View {
        if vm.results != nil{
            //You can probaly populate this picker with the keys in
            // baseCurrency.baseCur.baseS
            Picker("rates", selection: $vm.selectedBaseCurrency){
                ForEach((vm.results!.baseCurrencies.first?.value.sorted{$0.key < $1.key})!, id: \.key) { key, rate in
                    Text(key).tag(key)
                }
            }
        }else{
            Text("waiting...")
        }
    }
}
class CurrencyViewModel: ObservableObject{
    
    @Published var results: BaseCurrency?
    @Published var selectedBaseCurrency: String = "usd"{
        didSet{
            UpdateRates()
        }
    }
    init() {
        //If you can .onAppear you don't need it here
        //UpdateRates()
    }
    func UpdateRates() {
        print(#function)
        let baseUrl = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fawazahmed0/currency-api@1/latest/currencies/"
        let baseCur = selectedBaseCurrency   // usd
        let requestType = ".json"
        
        guard let url = URL(string: baseUrl + baseCur + requestType) else {
            print("Invalid URL")
            return
        }
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            if let data = data {
                do{
                    let decodedResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(BaseCurrency.self, from: data)
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        
                        if self.results == nil{
                            //Assign a new base currency
                            self.results = decodedResponse
                        }else{ //merge the existing with the new result
                            for base in decodedResponse.baseCurrencies.keys{
                                self.results?.baseCurrencies[base] = decodedResponse.baseCurrencies[base]
                            }
                        }
                        //update the UI
                        self.objectWillChange.send()
                    }
                    
                }catch{
                    //Error thrown by a try
                    print(error)//much more informative than error?.localizedDescription
                }
            }
            if error != nil{
                //data task error
                print(error!)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
struct CurrencyView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CurrencyView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks lorem ipsum for taking the time to look into this.  It was much more challenging than I first thought!
I would like to call the UpdateRates() method from onAppear (.onAppear(perform: CurrencyViewModel.UpdateRates()), but I am getting the error “Missing argument for parameter #1 in call. Fix: Insert ’<#CurrencyViewModel#>’.  The initialization logic doesn’t have an argument.

There must be an easier way but I’m calling this currency logic from the main tab view and then checking with some clock logic before updating the currency rates several times a day.

Comment: Impossible to know what is going on without seeing the code `(.onAppear(perform: CurrencyViewModel.UpdateRates())` This looks wrong though. That open parenthesis at the beginning is sketchy you are passing it as a parameter into something and `UpdateRates` doesn't return anything. Also, `CurrencyViewModel.UpdateRates()` is called wrong. It is not a `static` method as per my code.

Comment: The code I provided works on its own. If you put it into an empty project/swift file and run it on canvas or a device you will see how it all ties in. The Picker when moved to a new currency triggers a fetch and it gets added to the currencies already fetched.

Comment: I added an `onAppear()` call in `CurrencyView` so you can see how it would work.

Comment: Ok I got it running with these changes to my main tab view:
@StateObject var vm: CurrencyViewModel = CurrencyViewModel()
and call UpdateRates like this: .onAppear(perform: vm.UpdateRates)